# GCP cloudbuild.yaml conditional step error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

This is my cloud build file

```
substitutions:
        _CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE: us-central1-a 
        _CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER: $_CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER
    steps:
    - name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/sonar-scanner:latest
      entrypoint: 'bash'
      args:
      - '-c'
      - 'if [ $BRANCH_NAME != 'production' ]; then sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.test.io -Dsonar.login=${_SONAR_LOGIN} -Dsonar.projectKey=service -Dsonar.sources=. ; fi'
    - id: 'build test-service image'
      name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA', '.']
    - id: 'push test-service image'
      name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA']
    - id: 'set test-service image in yamls'
      name: 'ubuntu'
      args: ['bash','-c','sed -i "s,TEST_SERVICE,gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA," k8s/*.yaml']
    - id: kubectl-apply
      name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
      args: ['apply', '-f', 'k8s/']
      env:
      - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=${_CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE}'
      - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=${_CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER}'
    images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA']
```

I am getting error

> failed unmarshalling build config cloudbuild.yaml: yaml: line 17: did
>   not find expected key

**Update 1**

As per @cloudomation suggestion updated if condition

```
- 'if [ $BRANCH_NAME != "production" ]; then sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.test.io -Dsonar.login=${_SONAR_LOGIN} -Dsonar.projectKey=service -Dsonar.sources=. ; fi'
```

Condition is working but when it's true getting this error

```
Step #1: Digest: sha256:ef0de1c8e48544b9693b9aab2222bf849028bb66881762bf77e055b0abbf7f2b Step #1: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/wotnot-235414/sonar-scanner:latest Step #1: gcr.io/project-235414/sonar-scanner:latest Step #1: /opt/sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-linux/bin/sonar-scanner: exec: line 59: /opt/sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-linux/jre/bin/java: not found Finished Step #1 ERROR ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/project-235414/sonar-scanner:latest" failed: exit status 127
```

but when my step is like this way it's working perfectly

```
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/sonar-scanner:latest
  args:
    - '-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.test.io'
    - '-Dsonar.login=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    - '-Dsonar.projectKey=service-name'
    - '-Dsonar.sources=.'
```

also this is running that mean there no issue in builder image it's just issue of passing parameters

```
docker run gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/sonar-scanner:latest bash -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.test.io -Dsonar.login=${_SONAR_LOGIN} -Dsonar.projectKey=service -Dsonar.sources=.
```

**if condition working but after that then condition having some issue**

Comment: Could you test your container in the exact same condition. I means with the substitution variable `_SONAR_LOGIN` and the same `-Dsonar.projectKey=` value? It's maybe a parameter issue.

Comment: Yes it is running i want to update the condition

Comment: Is it work without the IF condition ?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes it is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape the quotes:

```
  - 'if [ $BRANCH_NAME != \'production\' ]; then sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.test.io -Dsonar.login=${_SONAR_LOGIN} -Dsonar.projectKey=service -Dsonar.sources=. ; fi'
```

or use double quotes:

```
  - 'if [ $BRANCH_NAME != "production" ]; then sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.test.io -Dsonar.login=${_SONAR_LOGIN} -Dsonar.projectKey=service -Dsonar.sources=. ; fi'
```

Comment: will try it thanks for writing answer. thanks a lot.

Comment: @HarshManvar it looks like there is no `/opt/sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-linux/jre/bin/java` in your image `gcr.io/wotnot-235414/sonar-scanner:latest`

Comment: But but when my step is like......it's working perfectly added step in question. Updated can you please have a look.

Comment: it's working if i donot add condition. if condition working but after then some issue is there.

Comment: I think that you conditional has some additional semicolons can you try this

`if [ $BRANCH_NAME != "production" ]; then
        then sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonar.test.io -Dsonar.login=${_SONAR_LOGIN} -Dsonar.projectKey=service -Dsonar.sources=.
      fi`

Please check the following example of yaml in order to check if something is missing 

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/master/cloudbuild.yaml