# Adding a “Are you sure …” dialog in GCP cloudbuild.yaml

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build

Basically, I want to add a `"Are you sure you want to run unit tests ?"` dialog before **step 2(run_test_test-coverage)** in my `cloudbuild.yaml`. How can I do that ? This can be done in jenkins but don't know how to do the same in GCP cloudbuild.

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'node:10.10.0'
  id: installing_npm
  args: ['npm', 'install']
  dir: 'API/system_performance'
- name: 'node:10.10.0'
  id: run_test_test-coverage
  args: ['npm', 'run', 'coverage']
  dir: 'API/system_performance'
```

Edit:
Below is my updated cloudbuild.yaml file:

```
- name: 'node:10.10.0'
  id: installing_npm
  args: ['npm', 'install']
  dir: 'API/groups'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  id: deploy
  dir: '/workspace/API/groups'
  entrypoint: bash
  args: 
   - '-c'
   - |
      if [ $BRANCH_NAME != "xoxoxoxox" ] 
      then 
        gcloud functions deploy groups &&\ 
        --region=us-central1 &&\
        --source=. &&\
        --trigger-http &&\ 
        --runtime=nodejs8 &&\ 
        --entry-point=App &&\ 
        --allow-unauthenticated &&\
        --service-account=xoxoxxooxox@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
      fi
```

Here, I get the build as successful, but when the condition becomes false, although build gets deployed successfully, yet I get the below output and the the build gets failed. Why so ?

```
Finished Step #0 - "installing_npm"
Starting Step #1 - "deploy"
Step #1 - "deploy": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #1 - "deploy": Created .gcloudignore file. See `gcloud topic gcloudignore` for details.
Step #1 - "deploy": Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...
Step #1 - "deploy": .....................done.
Step #1 - "deploy": availableMemoryMb: 256
Step #1 - "deploy": entryPoint: App
Step #1 - "deploy": httpsTrigger:
Step #1 - "deploy":   url: https://xoxoxoxo.cloudfunctions.net/groups
Step #1 - "deploy": ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
Step #1 - "deploy": labels:
Step #1 - "deploy":   deployment-tool: cli-gcloud
Step #1 - "deploy": name: projects/xoxoxoxo/locations/us-central1/functions/groups
Step #1 - "deploy": runtime: nodejs8
Step #1 - "deploy": serviceAccountEmail: xoxoxoxo@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
Step #1 - "deploy": sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/xoxoxo
Step #1 - "deploy": status: ACTIVE
Step #1 - "deploy": timeout: 60s
Step #1 - "deploy": updateTime: '2020-05-25T19:18:26.099Z'
Step #1 - "deploy": versionId: '12'
Step #1 - "deploy": bash: line 2:  : command not found
Step #1 - "deploy": bash: line 3: --region=us-central1: command not found
Step #1 - "deploy": bash: line 6: --runtime=nodejs8: command not found
Step #1 - "deploy": bash: line 7: --entry-point=App: command not found
Step #1 - "deploy": bash: line 8: --allow-unauthenticated: command not found
Finished Step #1 - "deploy"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 127
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't interact with Cloud Build. In fact, you send the file to a CI, and you wait for the result, no more.

But, you can customize the steps. I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235945/google-cloud-build-conditional-step/58239148#58239148) about the conditional step. Use a [substitution variable](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) for running your build with, or without the tests.

The choice won't be interactive, but at the build submission, you can have the choice.

-> I mean that when you submit the build, for example manually

```
gcloud build submit --substitions=_SKIPTEST=true
```

You choose to skip the tests at the submission, not during the build.

**EDIT**

When you perform a `bash -c |` imagine that you are on your linux terminal and enter line by line your commands in sequence. For multiline, add backslash `\`. Here the `&&` are useless. Use it for chaining command, but here it's useless because you execute command in sequence.

So here the correct steap

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  id: deploy
  dir: '/workspace/API/groups'
  entrypoint: bash
  args: 
   - '-c'
   - |
      if [ $BRANCH_NAME != "xoxoxoxox" ] 
      then 
        gcloud functions deploy groups \ 
        --region=us-central1 \
        --source=. \
        --trigger-http \ 
        --runtime=nodejs8 \ 
        --entry-point=App \ 
        --allow-unauthenticated \
        --service-account=xoxoxxooxox@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
      fi
```

Comment: I did not understand your last line `but at the build submission, you can have the choice`.

Comment: I edited my answer. Is it clearer? Do you know how to tackle your issue?

Comment: I got you. Could you please have a look at the `Edit` section in my question !

Comment: Because the [answer that you have accepted is wrong!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62002236/is-this-the-correct-way-to-write-if-else-statement-in-cloudbuild-yaml-file?noredirect=1#comment109675419_62002236). I updated my answer for correcting it!

Comment: I tried your code, but it won't work if the `if condition` becomes false. I get the same  `command not found` errors which is in the `edit` section.

Comment: How are you testing? Manually? or with a trigger?

Comment: Testing with trigger.

Comment: Are you sure that, in the question you have paste the lastest version of your CLoud Build.yaml. I tried a lot of combination, impossible to break my Cloud Build.

Comment: Yes. I have used your code. Your conditional statement works only if its true. For instance: it works in this case: `if [ xoxoxoxox != xoxoxoxox ]`, but it won't work for this case `if [ prod != xoxoxoxox ]`. Here, I get `command not found` errors.
So, just for now, I have used 2 cloudbuild.yaml files and named them something like this: `cloudbuild.yaml` and `cloudbuild_feature.yaml` without any conditional statements. But, this is not a good practice.