# Having a common YAML file for PUSH and TAG based trigger in Google cloud build

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build

I am trying to build a common YAML file for both push and tag-based triggers. I can build two YAML files and pass them to the triggers setting page in Google cloud build, but I want to have a common file for both of them.

In the push trigger, the YAML consists of unit testing and in the tag-based trigger, the YAML consists of unit testing and containerizing the application to be pushed to the artifact registry. As YAML is a text-formatting language and if/else conditions cannot be incorporated in it, how can I do this in one single file?

If you want any other information, please let me know and looking forward to help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are right, YAML doesn’t support conditional statements, but you can use GitLab to help you parse `if` statements as mentioned in [If condition is possible in YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61941510/15774177). With the help of this you will be able to add the respective code for Push and tag trigger in the same file.

Comment: Yeah you are right @Zeenath. But our organization is using GitHub only, so I guess I have no other way but to make separate files. Thank you for your time

Comment: Hi, I think you can still use if in the yaml file as shown in the [Google Cloud Build conditional step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58239148/15774177) and [Is this the correct way to write if-else in cloudbuild.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62004745/15774177), let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you so much for these resources. I am trying these and will let you know

Comment: So I am working in this repository https://github.com/Athe-kunal/cloud-build-samples/tree/v1.0.2/quickstart-automate. Here you can see the cloudbuild_common.yaml file which has the trigger instructions for both tags and push-based trigger. Can you please tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you receiving any error? or what's not working in this?

Comment: Here, it is not going inside the if loops. It is just executing the initial name line and then terminating.

Comment: Were you able to go through the repo and find what is wrong?

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to locate where have you gone wrong, it should work as mentioned in [Running Inline bash script](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts#running_inline_bash_scripts). As an alternative you can also try writing your code in separate bash script and calling it in .yaml file as mentioned in [Running bash script](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/run-bash-scripts#running_bash_scripts_on_disk).

Comment: Thank you Zeenath, this helped me a lot in